# Magento 2.5: Unable to open the customer grid in backend

Tags: magento2, admin

I need to modify query of orders/items.I get error when opening customer grid in backend

I get the following error:

> Item (Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document) with the same ID "269151" already exists.

Does anybody have any idea what would the issue be and where to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Did you installed any third party module?

Comment: Yes I have few third party modules

Comment: Disabled 3rd party modules for a minute and check it still error display or not?

Comment: I have tried to disable 3 rd party modules but still not working

Comment: Can you please upload your code? I want to see from where this error generate.

Comment: Can u please let me known which code u are talking about?

Comment: Did you use any custom code for that which is execute from your third party module?

Comment: No i have not use such code can u tell me if any changes to be made in database to remove duplicate entry?